# Issues publishing to Azure: cannot use imports when '--module' is 'none'

Tags: typescript, azure, vue.js, publish

I am doing a .NET and Vue project based on this template: https://github.com/danijelh/aspnetcore-vue-typescript-template

While I don't have issues publishing my project to local files but I got errors when publishing to Azure VM:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS1148  (TS) Cannot use imports, exports, or module augmentations when '--module' is 'none'.    Miscellaneous   ~\iceandfire\App.vue    36  Active
Error   TS1219  (TS) Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.    Miscellaneous   ~\iceandfire\App.vue    45  Active
Error   TS2307  (TS) Cannot find module 'vue-property-decorator'.   Miscellaneous   ~\iceandfire\App.vue    36  Active
Error   TS2307  (TS) Cannot find module 'vue-notification'. Miscellaneous   ~\iceandfire\App.vue    38  Active
```

And the code is

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'

import Notifications from 'vue-notification'

Vue.use(Notifications)

@Component({
    name: 'App'
})
export default class App extends Vue { }
</script>
```

I guess the strangest thing is the error happens only when publishing to Azure but all is good when publishing to local folder/files. And when I copied the published file to my Azure VM all is running fine.

Would appreciate any helps to resolve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same template and started a fresh project.
Followed below steps and deployed. It worked for me.

Installed Template:

```
dotnet new -i AspNetCore.Vue.TypeScript.Template
```

Project creation:

dotnet new vuetypescript --name Demo.Web

```
npm run build:prod
```

and then i deployed it . Please try with new project creation and try deploying.